# angularjs directive to angular6

Tags: angular

I have angular js directive as below in HTML

```
 <div>
    <body-compile compile="message.body" scope="{}" tosca-id="message-{{ $index }}-body-content"></body-compile>
 </div>
```

& in  .js file I have as below :

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';

    var base = require('base');
    var utils = base.utils;

    configCompile.$inject = ['$compileProvider'];
    module.exports = configCompile;

    function configCompile($compileProvider) {

        $compileProvider.directive('bodyCompile', bodyCompile);

function bodyCompile($compile) {
            // directive factory creates a link function
            return {
                scope: {
                    compile: "=",
                    scope: "=?",
                },
                link: link,
            }

            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                var scope_child = scope.$new();

                scope.$watch('compile', function () {

                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

                scope.$watch('scope', function () {
                        scope.scope = scope.scope || {};
                        scope_child = scope.$new();
                        for (var idx in scope.scope) {
                            scope_child[idx] = scope.scope[idx];
                        }
                        scope_child.$this = scope.scope;

                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

            };
        };
    }
```

this function is being used for for showing existing coversations ( more then one ) and creating new message so generally message.body could have one or more then one messages into it.

Since I dont have much knowledge of angularJS, I was wondering what is best way I can replace it with angular 6 directive, shall I have to use directive with two @Input parameters like scope ? body ?.

If one can just give hint on this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It's quite a job to transfer an app from angularjs to angular 2+. You'd be better starting from the start. Since there is no `scope` in angular, you can't simply keep that code and replace some variable here and there. You could still look into [the angular upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) but i doubt you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: I know it is tough job,but what I am looking is to what is equivalent to angular, I am expert at angular6

Comment: or is there any way I can use same directive wiith angular6 ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer here. From what i understand, you are compiling a angular component dynamically. You could look into [Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), this might be what you are looking for.